# Javascript scraper logging in

Tags: javascript, cookies, request

I seem to be doing something wrong.

I have a student website that I want to scrape, but first I need to log in. Currently I have a python scraper that does it. The website logs in with a post request to a url containing a sid and PIN.

```
var login_url = 'https://example.com';

var formData = {
    sid: 'username',
    PIN: 'password'
}
```

How would I go about creating the same scraper but with javascript? I have seen the request library, which seems like what I want to use but cannot get it to work.

Comment: https://github.com/request/request#forms

Comment: @doublesharp Thanks, i've seen that and tried it but it still doesn't log in.

Comment: I just posted an example as an answer. Make sure you inspect the results in the callback to make sure the server isn't responding with an error, etc.

Comment: There are a few things wrong with you update. First, if you use `const` you can't reassign the variable, so `request = request.defaults({ jar: true });` will fail. The main thing however is that you are not requesting the proper URL, so it's unlikely this a direct copy of the python code. The URL you are using hosts the firm, the `POST` submits it to `https://central.carleton.ca/prod/twbkwbis.P_ValLogin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `request` module to [POST the form data](https://github.com/request/request#forms) to your endpoint. The response from the server will be in the call back to the `.post()` method.

```
const request = require('request');
// do not reassign "request", if you need to set properties us a different variable

// use the action= value from the form for the URL
const url = 'https://central.carleton.ca/prod/twbkwbis.P_ValLoginn';
const data = {
    sid: 'username',
    PIN: 'password',
};

request.post({ url: url, formData: data }, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('failed', err);
    } else {
        console.log('the response', body);
    }
});
```

If you are interesting in parsing the resulting HTML I recommend using [CheerioJS](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) - much like jQuery but server side.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I tried the code out but still cannot get it to work. The problem seems to be with the URL, however it works in my python scraper. Is it potentially not the one I need for javascript? I got the URL by monitoring the post request sent after log in using chrome's network tab.

Comment: I updated the answer with the correct URL you should use. I ran the code and it works, I just get an authentication error as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I incorporated it with cookies and it worked perfectly!